# Is it possible to use geth attach with a different keystore?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have set up geth to run as a systemd service (in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) as system user `ethereum`. The datadir is set to `/blockchain/ethereum`. After fiddling with permissions and groups, I managed to add my standard user account to the same group as my geth user, and I can use `geth --datadir /blockchain/ethereum attach` from a terminal to access the geth console.

My problem is that I have my keystore in my home directory, and when I try `geth --datadir /blockchain/ethereum --keystore ~/.keystore attach` and I check the `personal` object, I do not see my account listed.

So my question is, is it possible to connect to a running geth from a different user if I specify my own keystore?

Comment: The `geth` process needs to be able to read the file. That means that the user which owns the `geth` process has to be able to read the file. Are you comfortable giving that user read permissions?

Comment: @cleanunicorn I guess I am. The reason for the separation is that my home folder is on an encrypted drive while the datadir for geth is on a separate unencrypted drive. The reason for drive encryption on the main drive is to protect data from snooping when the system is off, so that shouldn't be a problem. I'll try changing the permissions of my keystore.

Comment: @DanielLucaCleanUnicorn simply changing the permissions of the keystore folder in my home directory did work. I had to add the keystore directory to geth when it starts up. It seems so far that it is not possible to specify a different keystore with `geth attach`